# How to switch on 3G modem local area connection from c++ application?

Tags: winapi, network-programming, c++builder

Basically my c++builder application uses wired net connection. But as backup channel I have a 3G modem inserted in desktop port and local area connection is created for it. It could be set whether connection will be run automatically or manually.

I'm looking for some possibility to control this connection from my c++ application. Preferably on the LAN connection level (disable\enable). Or maybe on switching connection on\off (but I'm afraid it could be specific for each modem model.)

Windows XP is installed on desktop.

Comment: Much luck. Try ipworks. Perhaps this can help You. Under linux netlink libs are useful. But as long as You have no control over the device ( issue the os to communicate with the driver of the modem, or You haven't created a driver Yourself), You only could try to get the api which turn on/of rf-switch of windows. And even this is not so trivial.